# TLS Connection with no Keystore

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I am stumped as to how my client program is able to create an SSLSocket and connect to a server program successfully even though the keystore file (sessionKeyStore below) is null.

The following code will successfully create a TLSv1.2 socket with a null keystore and successfully handshake with my server program which I thought always requires a key exchange.

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");

tmf.init(sessionKeyStore); // sessionKeyStore IS NULL!!

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(sessionKeyStore, SSL_PASSWORD.toCharArray()); // password is not null
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
SecureRandom sc = createSecureRandom();
sc.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), sc);
SSLSocketFactory factory = sc.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(server, serverPort);
((SSLSocket) socket).startHandshake();
```

Comment: The client only needs a keystore if the server requests the client certificate. And keystores are in the file system, not the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that client authentication is not included in the basic TLS handshake.  Only the server is authenticated.  Client authentication is a separate handshake that occurs after the server is first authenticated and only if the server requests it.  The problem was I needed to specifically tell the Server Socket to demand that the client certificate verification be included in the TLS handshake.  The way to do that in Java JSSE is by adding the following code to the server side:

```
SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(port);
// Add the below to force a certificate request on the client.
sslserversocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
```

https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/tls-encryption